# CSS horizontal menu issue - buttons on multiple lines text

Tags: css, button, text, menu

I have this simple horizontal menu with square buttons that **have text on multiple lines**.
I want them to appear centered vertical. I tried many solutions and nothing seems to work.
Here is the code, feel free to edit. Keep the buttons square and text on multiple lines.

**I want the text in the yellow box to be centered in the middle of the yellow box. VERTICALLY**

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#">Text1</a></li>    
    <li> <a href="#">Short</a></li>    
    <li> <a href="#">3 ROW THIS IS LONGER</a></li>    
    <li> <a href="#">2 ROWS TEXT</a></li>    
    <li> <a href="#">Text3</a></li>    
    <li> <a href="#">Text6</a></li>    
    <li> <a href="#">Text3</a></li>    
    <li> <a href="#">MORE TEXT HERE</a></li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div * {
  display:block;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  background-color:red;   
  width: 496px;
  height: 62px;
}

li{
  display:inline-block;
  width:62px;
  height:62px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:green;
  float:left;
}

a{
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color:yellow;
  font-size:12px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-family:Arial;
  width:58px;
  height:58px;
  padding:0px;
  margin:2px;
}

a:hover{
  background-color:white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/58MyY/

Thanks

Comment: what do u need to be centered? the text? or the div perse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unsure of what you're describing, but I think this is it:

**Update**
I think this is what he is looking for.

You can get this vertical align easily by using display:table-cell and vertical-align:middle together.

```
li{
   display:table-row;
}

a{
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/58MyY/4/

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain it clear. It's 4am here.  I want the text in the yellow box to be centered in the middle of the yellow box. VERTICALLY

Comment: Okay. Set the li to table-row and a to table-cell, then vertical-align:middle. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/58MyY/4/

Comment: I clined up everything. Here is the complete menu if anyone interested:  http://jsfiddle.net/58MyY/6/

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest a good place to see some examples: http://www.cssplay.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

As Dominick has shown with less markup you can use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` to do the trick. The problem with only using that is that you lose your margins / padding

Here's a version that shows the right borders and whatnot using some div wrappers.

http://jsfiddle.net/58MyY/5/

**EDIT** >> Alas I noticed the hover effect is not exactly what you desired on the link inside the `li` elements.